# Saving decimal separator "," instead of "." in zend framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, decimal, setlocale

I am searching for a way to save the decimal separator "," in de_DE Locale into the database or even away to auto convert the de_DE to en_EN while the inserting process.

Comment: Which data type is it stored in the database? float?

Comment: A floating point cannot have a ','. More about float [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html). The decimal point is generated by Zend while converting the field from float to string and is parsed when writing to it. You should make a wrapper function or see if you can change the conversion between float and string. Sadly I don't know enough about Zend to give you a specific answer.

Comment: ok thanks for you effort

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Zend filter like that:

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_NormalizedToLocalized(array('precision' => 2));
```

see the [doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.localizedtonormalized.numberslocal) for more details.